# Unchecked cast java.io.Serializable to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Help please, I get the following message, in the following code that I have:

```
listaFinal = (ArrayList<PuntoNota>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miLista");

AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(this, listaFinal);
```

**PuntoNota.java**

```
public class PuntoNota implements Serializable{
private String punto;
private String nota;

public PuntoNota (String punto, String nota){
    this.punto = punto;
    this.nota = nota;
}

public String getPunto(){
    return punto;
}


public String getNota(){
    return nota;
}

}
```

**AdapterDatos:**

```
public AdapterDatos(Context context, ArrayList<PuntoNota> puntoNotaList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.puntoNotaList = puntoNotaList;
}
```

The application is working well, but I get the following message:

> Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable' to 'java.util.ArrayList ' less ... (Ctrl + F1).
>     about this code: (ArrayList ) getIntent (). getSerializableExtra ("myList"); will it be advisable to delete or hide this message?

Comment: It's just warning message.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn but solving cast from serializable to the respective desired generic list will add to good coding practices. Otherwise, when you use Parcelable, data types are known in advance at both ends, and this issue is resolved.

Comment: it happens to warn about usage, not for compile code checking. Your solution only hide it, not solve it either. so live with it unless changing to type safe serializable

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Root cause:** This is a warning from IDE, `getSerializableExtra` return a `Serializable`, and you are trying to convert to `ArrayList<PuntoNota>`. It might throw **ClassCastException** at runtime if the programe cannot cast it to your expected type.

**Solution:** In android to pass a user-defined object around, your class should implements `Parcelable` instead of `Serializable` interface.

```
class PuntoNota implements Parcelable {
    private String punto;
    private String nota;

    public PuntoNota(String punto, String nota) {
        this.punto = punto;
        this.nota = nota;
    }

    protected PuntoNota(Parcel in) {
        punto = in.readString();
        nota = in.readString();
    }

    public String getPunto() {
        return punto;
    }

    public String getNota() {
        return nota;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(punto);
        dest.writeString(nota);
    }

    public static final Creator<PuntoNota> CREATOR = new Creator<PuntoNota>() {
        @Override
        public PuntoNota createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new PuntoNota(in);
        }

        @Override
        public PuntoNota[] newArray(int size) {
            return new PuntoNota[size];
        }
    };
}
```

At sender side

```
ArrayList<PuntoNota> myList = new ArrayList<>();
// Fill data to myList here
...
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("miLista", myList);
```

At receiver side

```
ArrayList<? extends PuntoNota> listaFinal = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("miLista");
```

Answer (score 12):

You can set a warning Suppression `@SuppressWarnings` annotation.

Example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
listaFinal = (ArrayList<PuntoNota>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("miLista");
```

It is an annotation to suppress compile warnings about unchecked generic operations (not exceptions), such as casts. It essentially implies that the programmer did not wish to be notified about these which he is already aware of when compiling a particular bit of code.

You can read more on this specific annotation here:

> [SuppressWarnings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html)

Additionally, Oracle provides some tutorial documentation on the usage of annotations here:

> [Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html)

As they put it,

> "The 'unchecked' warning can occur when interfacing with legacy code written before the advent of generics (discussed in the lesson titled Generics)."

Comment: My eyes are relaxed now by this trick, thank you.
Also you should put `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` right above your method

Comment: You can put it above class declaration as well. It will remove all the warnings related to this.