# How to pass multidimensional Arraylist to another activity using bundle

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to pass an a multidimensional arraylist (ex: Arraylist>) from one java activity to another. I've looked at many posts and have determined using a bundle is the best way to go (i am also already using a bundle elsewhere so i know how they generally work), however I haven't seen an example of a 2d arraylist.

I've tried something along the line of the following, but didn't get far after realizing putStringArrayListExtra doesnt accept 2d arraylists:

```
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bigArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<String> smallArrayList= new ArrayList<>();

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putStringArrayListExtra("2dArrayList", bigArrayList );
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(b);

ArrayList<String> urls = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("2dArrayList");
```

Just looking for some help or advice on how to pass 2d arraylists between activities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass 2D array to another Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214847/pass-2d-array-to-another-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Gson library for this, no need to implement serializable.

Suppose your arraylist is :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bigArrayList= new ArrayList<>();
```

After that, you can add it to the intent as below :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("data", new Gson().toJson(bigArrayList));
```

You can later retrieve this in Activity2 as below :

```
String extra = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bigArrayList= new Gson().fromJson(extra, new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>(){}.getType());
```

It works for me! I hope It helps you!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I haven't tried this yet. But I hope this helps.</strike>
I have tried the code, It's working.

**Current Activity**

```
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bigArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtra("bigArrayList", bigArrayList);
```

**Next Activity**

Parse the serialize data to `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, to pass the value to `urls` variable.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> urls = (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("bigArrayList");
```

Comment: I have tried this, and it is giving me the following error. . .
Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable' to 'java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>>'

Comment: Did the error occur on run time or on the compilation?

Comment: If it's just a warning, try to run your code. It should work.

Comment: It works when the code runs, but just wondering if the warning is something i can ignore or will affect performance later on and should be resolved now.

Comment: Just make sure you're parsing the same data type/object. Since we are parsing the same ```ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>``` it would definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

**ActivityA.java**

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ddArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        a.add("A");
        ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
        b.add("B");
        ddArray.add(a);
        ddArray.add(b);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("ARRAY",ddArray);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
```

**TestActivity.java**

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> array = (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("ARRAY");
```

Comment: I have tried this, it too gives me the same error as NJY404's response:
Unchecked cast: 'java.io.Serializable' to 'java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>>'

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805648/unchecked-cast-java-io-serializable-to-java-util-arraylist) link and you will get the clarification as to why it is showing the warning and how to prevent it.